# Can I make an Eloquent model load a relationship with an sql JOIN instead of generating separate sql queries?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, orm

I'm a developer coming from CakePHP and making my first project with Laravel.
In CakePHP when I defined a model and its relations, there was an option to set the join strategy on a relationship: `strategy` (`join` or `select`). By default it uses `join` and when I load a related model, it will do so in a single query by adding a `JOIN` statement. You could optionally use `select` which would generate a separate query.

Now, when I'm using eager loading in Laravel, for example:

```php
$user = App\User::with(['articles'])->first();
```

This actually results in two queries being generated, one for getting the user's record, and one for getting the associated articles. This is the same as if I had specified the `select` strategy in my CakePHP model. However, I would like to use the `join` strategy instead, so I can do things like ordering by or filtering by a related table's column. I haven't found any way to do this yet. Does something like this exist in laravel/eloquent?

Comment: It's not possible out of the box, it would require changing a lot of code in eloquent. Also this approach won't make sense for one-to-many and many-to-many relationships since it will load the main model data n times.

Comment: @EliasSoares why would it not make sense? Again, CakePHP has this option, and so do many other frameworks, and they work just fine with n-n, 1-n relationships.

Comment: It work, but think in the data being transfered between mysql and PHP. It will be larger since the main model data will repeat n times.

Answer (score 0):

With Laravel its quite simple fetching records using Joins.
Assuming left join this is a sample code to fetch your records:(You could as well use any of the joins-most suitable to your needs)

```
//assuming **title** and **description** as amongst the article fields
// and that you've passed the user's id as **$user_id**
//I've also assumed the articles table has a user id field **user_id** which has the corresponding user's id.
    $user = App\User::leftJoin('articles','users.id','articles.user_id')
->where('users.id',$user_id)
->select('users.*','artcles.title as title','articles.description as description')
->get();
```

Comment: Yes, I know that I can manually make joins. But the whole point of defining the relationship on my eloquent model is to get around manually writing joins and letting eloquent do it for me.